# Show User Registration Screen Only Once

Tags: javascript, html

I am building an Android Application using HTML, CSS, JS. On the welcome screen I have a **Registration** button which helps to register first time user on a web-server. Everything works fine till here. However, when the user closes the app and again opens it the welcome screen (with the Registration button) opens.
*Now I want to know how to hide / disable the Registration button once the user is successfully registered?*
The Welcome screen will instead show another message (already implemented). Right now the user can see both the registration button and the message.

```
 <p>Welcome</p>

    <h1 class="title">ApplicationName</h1>
    <div class="line submit">
        <br/><input type="submit" class="classname" onclick="regUser()" value="Registration" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either store the user info in the form of cookies or get it from the backend. And if the user already exists, you can use

`document.querySelector(".submit").style.display = "none"`

to hide that button.

Comment: Somehow the above did not work so i used : document.getElementById("check").style.display = "none"; //check is the ID given to the div.
Now the routing is happening based on the response from the werbserver. However, when no user is registered the control automatically executes the registration button and login-create screen opens (even without the user clicking on the "Registratio" button. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: added a check on the contextID and it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

resolved with the use of document.getElementById("check").style.display = "none"; and with a check on the contextID from the app history.